# Why we can not differentiate functions that have closed ball domain?

Tags: general-topology, derivatives, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Why we can not differentiate functions that have closed ball domain?

I think this comes from the idea that we can not differentiate functions that have closed intervals domain, as in this case we can study differentiation on the open interval and then study differentiation from the left at the end point of the interval and study differentiation from right at the starting point of the interval. am I correct?

If so how can I explain this for functions having closed ball domain?

Thanks!

Comment: You are correct. Consider a point on the boundary of the ball. As in the closed interval, we cannot take the derivative in each direction.

Comment: @JohnDouma why? and in the case of the ball there are several directions not justleft and right ..... sohow we differentiate a closed ball?

Comment: The function is not defined there. We are on the boundary of the ball and the function is only defined on the ball. Imagine taking a ball around this boundary point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no *intrinsic* reason not to define a derivative of a function defined on a closed ball, at a point on the boundary on that ball.

In more detail, if $B = \{x\in\mathbb R^n: |x|\le R\}$ and $f:B\to \mathbb R^m$, then for any point $x_0$ domain of $f$ we can define that the derivative of $f$ at $x_0$ means a linear mapping $T$ such that
$$ f(x) = f(x_0) + T(x-x_0) + o(x-x_0) $$
for $x\to x_0$ and $x\in B$.

Even at the boundary points of $B$, there are neighborhoods of the ball that are rich enough that the derivative is unique if it exists. (All that's needed for this is that every neighborhood of $x_0$ relative to $B$ contains points whose difference from $x_0$ span $\mathbb R^n$).

The reason why textbooks often don't do this is that most of what they want to say can be said quite fine while restricting our attention to *open* domains, and doing so is quite a bit simpler -- there are (literally!) fewer edge cases that need to be considered when stating the results.

For one example of one such corner case, consider the function
$$ f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } y < x \\
0 & \text{if } y > 4x \\
0 & \text{if } x = y = 0 \\
1 & \text{if } 2x < y < 3x \\
\text{undefined} & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$
whose partial derivatives exist and are continuous (indeed identically $0$) everywhere in the domain of $f$, but $f$ is not even continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: But if the  domain of the function $f$ is not open we can not speak about partial derivatives of it ..... correct? if so why?

Comment: @Idonotknow, correct: Partial deriviatives need more than I describe here. A _most_ points on the boundary of a closed ball we could speak of partial derivitives well enough, but there are some points that are exceptions -- for example, for $f$ defined on the closed unit disk, $\partial f/\partial x$ would not make sense at $(0,1)$.

Comment: why partial derivative at that point would not make sense?

Comment: @Idonotknow: Because $x\mapsto f(x,1)$ is only defined at $x=0$, and even with the definition above you can't meaningfully take a derivative at an isolated point. See new addition to answer for an even more dramatic example of things going "wrong".

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on what type of function and derivative you are thinking of. I assume you are thinking of the usual definition of the total derivative of a function between real vector spaces. In this case, your intuition is correct!

Consider some function *f* defined on some ball B(0,R) of radius R sitting inside Real n-space. Since any derivative( given it exists ) at a point *p*
is a measure of change in the output of *f* coming from an infinitesimal change in the input around *p*, you have to be able to change the input approaching *p* from the direction you are measuring the change.

Suppose *p* is on the boundary of the ball.  At *p* it makes sense to talk about directional derivatives in directions pointing into the ball, but not out of it. However since there are directions in which we cannot change the input ( or cannot approach *p* from ) we cannot express the rate of change at *p* in all directions, which is the data of the total derivative.

Another way of thinking about total derivatives is as a linearization( I.e. linear map )of the function, which approximates *f* around *p*, thus one needs to have a “tiny vector space” i.e an open ball, consisting of tangent vectors around *p* in order for *f* to have a chance to exist.

I hope that this comment was useful.

Comment: Actually, directional derivatives (ordinarily) are interpreted as two-sided, not single-sided, so when you compute a directional derivative of the direction of $\vec v$ pointing into the ball, the definition still requires that you look at $f(p+t\vec v)$ for $t<0$, and there you're out of luck.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! My overview of the literature is still lacking, so I am thankful that you took the time to improve my answer.